# Crud operation Of kendo ui Grid using json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want a kendo UI MVC 4 or 5 c# Grid with Add,Edit,Delete using ajax json and Sqlserver demo curd opeartion.

Any one can help me out..

Here i am using a simple method but it is not working properly..

```
    <script>
$(function () {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetAllUsers","Task")",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Edit","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(data,type)
            {
                return kendo.stringify(data.models);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false },
                        UserName: { type: "string" },
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        Address: { type: "string" },
                        IsActive: { type: "boolean" },
                        DateCreated: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
    });

    $("#allUsers").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:dataSource,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
        { field: "UserName",title: "User Name" },
        { field: "FirstName",title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName",title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "Address",title: "Address" },
        { field: "IsActive",title: "Active" },
        { field: "DateCreated",title: "Join Date",format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" },
        { command: "destroy" }
        ],
        toolbar: ["save","cancel"],
        editable: {
            mode: "incell",
            update: true,
            destroy: true,
            confirmation:true
        },
        edit: function (event) {
            console.log("at edit event");

        },
        save: function(event)
        {
            console.log("at saveChanges event");
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

So any one can guide me??

Don't send me the link of telerik website..just give me a solutions or code..

Comment: What is your problem ? What do you want ?

Comment: I want a simple inline grid with crud opeartion using json and sql server..along with all the validation

Comment: @MuratGündeş EXAMPLE LIKE  http://www.mitechdev.com/2016/06/implementing-kendo-grid-with-crud-operations-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use this Kendo Grid Html Sample;

```
       <!-- BEGIN KendoGrid -->
        <div>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SampleViewModel>()
            .Name("KendoGrid")
            .Scrollable()
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound("").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button' onclick=\"deleteSample(#=Id#)\"><span class='k-icon k-delete'></span>Delete</a>").Width(85).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound("").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button' href=\"/Sample/Edit/#= Id #\"><span class='k-icon k-edit'></span>Edit</a>").Width(130).Sortable(false);
                columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
                columns.Bound(x => x.Code);
                columns.Bound(x => x.Regex);
                columns.Bound(x => x.StatusText);
            })
             .Pageable(pager => pager
                    .Input(true)
                    .Numeric(false)
                    .Info(true)
                    .PreviousNext(true)
                    .Refresh(true))
                .Scrollable()
                .Sortable()
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(10)
                    .ServerOperation(true)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetSampleList", "Sample"))
                    ))
        </div>
        <!-- END KendoGrid -->
```

Delete button will open the popup if you want.
Edit button will be open the edit page.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = x.GetById(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

And GetSampleList; (It is already json)

```
public JsonResult GetSampleList()
{
     var list = x.GetSampleList();     
     return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: SampleViewModel The type or namespace couldnot be found

Comment: You have to create a viewmodel. This will be your data's model.

Comment: I have created a model name SampleViewModel

Comment: @model  IEnumerable<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.SampleViewModel>

Comment: In the top of the view page i also declared..but error The type or namespace couldnot be found in SampleViewModel